# Jmeter JSON API CSRF token value issue

Tags: jmeter

In **j meter** I getting Access denied for user anonymous however I change json API extractor also.

```
variable name='token' and j son expression =""$token":"(.+?)""
```

still unable to do.

Can you please help how and where I have to put j meter extractor?

Answer (score 0):

1. It appears that your trying to extract the token from [JSON](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON) and using Regular Expressions is not the best idea as extra space or line break may ruin your test. Since JMeter 3.0 there is [JSON Extractor](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSON_Extractor) which allows extracting data from JSON responses using [JSON Path](https://github.com/json-path/JsonPath) language. The relevant JSON Path expression will be as simple as:

   ```
   $..token
   ```
2. With regards to "where to put" - it depends on your application implementation, JSON Extractor obeys [JMeter Scoping Rules](https://wiki.apache.org/jmeter/UserManual/ScopingRules)

   - If you need to extract the token only once and from only one [HTTP Request](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request) sampler - put the JSON Extractor **as a child** of this sampler.
   - If you need to extract the token from each and every HTTP Request sampler - you need to put the JSON Extractor to be **at the same level** as HTTP Request samplers.

More information: [API Testing With JMeter and the JSON Extractor](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/api-testing-with-jmeter-and-the-json-extractor)